# from mutate_at to mutate(across(, also .names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm recoding survey responses (character) to a set of questions (that are not in continuous columns), and I was thrilled to get the following code to work:

```
#make a list of the selected columns


fcols <- c(2, 6, 8, 9, 14)

#recode the selected columns

d <- d %>% mutate_at(vars(fcols),
    ~(recode(.,
           "OriginalResponse1" = "NewResponse1",
           "OriginalResponse2" = "NewResponse2",
           "OriginalResponse3" = "NewResponse3",
           "OriginalResponse4" = "NewResponse4",
           .default = NA_character_)))
```

My main question has to do with making this work with "across", since "mutate_at" is apparently superseded.

I tried the below - put in the "across", and make sure to add a new closed paren at the end - but it doesn't work:

```
d <- d %>% mutate(across(vars(fcols),
    ~(recode(.,
           "OriginalResponse1" = "NewResponse1",
           "OriginalResponse2" = "NewResponse2",
           "OriginalResponse3" = "NewResponse3",
           "OriginalResponse4" = "NewResponse4",
           .default = NA_character_))))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `quosures`.
i It must be numeric or character.
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
```

Also, I've been trying to create a new set of columns (rather than just changing the existing ones) using the .names argument, after the .default argument, but I haven't been able to get that to work, except once only partially - when the columns appeared but they were all empty.

Main question: what am I missing in converting this to "across" from the working "mutate_at" version?

Bonus: how do I get the .names part to work?

Answer (score 0):

For `across` when you have `fcols` as numbers you don't need `vars` -

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% mutate(across(fcols,
                    ~recode(.,
                             "OriginalResponse1" = "NewResponse1",
                             "OriginalResponse2" = "NewResponse2",
                             "OriginalResponse3" = "NewResponse3",
                             "OriginalResponse4" = "NewResponse4",
                             .default = NA_character_)))
```

`.names` is useful when you want to keep the original columns as it is and create new columns.

```
d %>% mutate(across(fcols,
                    ~recode(.,
                             "OriginalResponse1" = "NewResponse1",
                             "OriginalResponse2" = "NewResponse2",
                             "OriginalResponse3" = "NewResponse3",
                             "OriginalResponse4" = "NewResponse4",
                             .default = NA_character_), .names = '{col}_new'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can wrap with `all_of` instead of `vars`.  Also, `recode` can take a named `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
nm1 <- setNames(str_c("NewResponse", 1:4), 
           str_c("OriginalResponse", 1:4))
d %>% 
mutate(across(all_of(fcols),
                    ~recode(., !!! nm1,
                             .default = NA_character_)))
```